# How can I display flags according to language ? Symfony 6.0.2

Tags: symfony, emoji, country-codes

I would like to display emoji according to language selected.

I followed a this solution but it works only for countries : https://medium.com/p/f794f39e6ac9

But I would like to do it for languages so that when I select a language and I can have the right emoji flag next to it.

How can I do it ?

Here is what I have tried :

> Change `Countries` => `Languages` and `CountryType` => `LanguageType` is not enough.

> I currently use `0x1F1A5` which is country code.

> Is there a language code I can use ?

*EmojiType.php*

```
<?php

namespace App\Form\Both;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\ChoiceList;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CountryType;
use Symfony\Component\Intl\Countries;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Options;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class EmojiType extends AbstractType
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return CountryType::class;
    }

    public static function getEmojiFlag(string $countryCode): string
    {
        $regionalOffset = 0x1F1A5;

        return mb_chr($regionalOffset + mb_ord($countryCode[0], 'UTF-8'), 'UTF-8')
            . mb_chr($regionalOffset + mb_ord($countryCode[1], 'UTF-8'), 'UTF-8');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
      // Define defaults options
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            // Dfine the list to display
            'choice_loader' => function (Options $options) {
                return ChoiceList::lazy($this, function () use ($options) {
                    $choices = [];
                    // Countries::getNames() return an array with the country code as key and the country name as value
                    // we fetch all countries code with country name translated according to the locale.
                    $countriesCode = Countries::getNames($options['choice_translation_locale']);
                     
                    foreach ($countriesCode as $countryCode => $displayed) {
                        // we create an array with the country code as key and we concatenate the emoji
                        // and the country name as value.
                        $choices[$countryCode] = self::getEmojiFlag($countryCode) . ' ' . $displayed;
                    }
                    
                    return array_flip($choices);
                });
            },
            // define the option to define the country by the locale
            'choice_translation_locale' => null,
        ]);
         
        // define the allowed type
        $resolver->setAllowedTypes('choice_translation_locale', ['null', 'string']);
    }
}
```

*NewLanguage.php*

```
<?php

namespace App\Form\Both;

use App\Entity\Language;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class NewLanguageType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('code', EmojiType::class)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Language::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: But Language is not equal to country (and therefore flag). How many countries speak English? Or Spanish? or French? How many countries have more than one "official language"? The correlation is not one-to-one.

Comment: Ok, I understand if it's not possible.